# Bash скрипт. Выполнение команд из файла

Tags: bash

Прошу оказать помощь.

Необходимо реализовать bash скрипт, который позволит команды из файла ( 1 строка - 1 команда, команды независимы друг от друга, порядок выполнения не важен). Результат выполнения каждой команды сохранить в отдельный файл.

**Обновление**

Должны, соответствено, получить файл по каждой команде с перечнем портов.
Проверил. Да, действительно есть непечатаемые символы \r \n. Подскажите, как убрать. Убрал, Спасибо.

Comment: ОС какая?

Если запускаете в \*nix, то может у Вас в файле конец строки `\r\n`?  
(из винды)

Comment: проверьте файл на непечатные символы: od -c script.txt

Comment: @Костя_12, я обычно использую `tr -d "\r"`.

Т.е. в предложенном Вам в ответе скрипте просто добавьте эту команду в конвейер к `cat` 

    ... cat script.txt | tr -d "\r"  | while ....

--

Кстати, кроме (или вместо) изменения текста вопроса пишите комментарии (правда, их количество ограничено 4 шт., но старые можно удалять)  т.к. иначе оповещения по почте об изменениях в вопросе не приходят (и увидел я их, можно сказать, случайно).

--

О причинах Вашей проблемы можно [почитать тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: Получил файл ip-адресов 1-строка адрес из команды
1.2.3.4
2.3.4.5 
 итд.
Как как n присваивать имена файлам, что они имели вид 1.2.3.4.res, 2.3.4.5.res

Comment: Может, стоит использовать python или perl. Для обработки текста - perl - лучший выбор.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
n=0; cat script.txt | while read command; do $command 2>&1 >$n.res; ((n++)); done
```

Comment: Попробовал. Получил ответ
. Note in particular that square brackets [] are no longer allowed. They were redundant and can simply be removed.


Comment: +Костя_12 привидите содержимое фйла, без этого непонятно,
скрипт сам по себе работоспособен, хотя cat лишний, можно написать так:

    n=0; while read command; do $command >& $n.res; ((n++)); done <script.txt

Comment: Получил файл ip-адресов 1-строка адрес из команды
1.2.3.4
2.3.4.5 
 итд.
Как как n присваивать имена файлам, что они имели вид 1.2.3.4.res, 2.3.4.5.res

Comment: `2>&1 >file` отличается от `>file 2>&1`. Первое выражение перенаправляет поток ошибок (stderr) в стандартный поток (stdout) -- в текущее его значение. Второе выражение перенаправляет оба потока в файл. Чтобы не путаться, можно использовать `&>`, предложенный @sercxjo (bash-синтакс, чтобы перенаправить оба стандартных потока).

Можно запустить все команды параллельно: добавить `&` в конце команды и `wait` после цикла.

Answer (score 0):

Не самый быстрый вариант (потребует запуска нового grep над каждой строкой):

```
name_file=`grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)" <<< "$command"`
```

Ещё можно использовать возможности bash по обработке регулярных выражений

```
if [[ "$command" =~ (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?) ]]; then name_file=$BASH_REMATCH.res ; else name_file=$n.res ; fi
```

Comment: Чтобы не делать этого (запуск нового grep над каждой строкой), есть awk.

Comment: Добавляйте четыре пробела в начало строки в своих комментариях, чтобы все символы были видны как они есть

Comment: Перенес в отдельный вопрос